# php strtotime first day of next month returns nothing

Tags: php, strtotime

I've been reading about problems in php with strtotime and "next month" issues. What i want to make is counter of months between two dates.
For example if I have start date 01.02.2012 and stop date 07.04.2012 I'd like to get return value - 3 months. Also 3 months would be the result if start date i 28.02.2012 and 07.04.2012. I am not counting exact number of days/months, just a number of months I have between two dates. It's not a big deal to make it with some strange date, mktime and strtotime usage, but unfortunatelly start and stop dates might be in two different years so

```
mktime(0,0,0,date('m')+1,1,date('Y');
```

isnt going to work (i do not now the year and if it changes between start and stop date. i can calculate it but it is not nice solution). Perfect solution would be to use:

```
$stat = Array('02.01.2012', '07.04.2012')
$cursor = strtotime($stat[0]);
$stop = strtotime($stat[1]);
$counter = 0;
    while ( $cursor < $stop ) {
   $cursor = strtotime("first day of next month", $cursor);
   echo $cursor . '<br>';
   $counter++;
   if ( $counter > 100) { break; } // safety break;
    }
    echo $counter . '<br>';
```

Unfortunatelly strtotime isnt returning proper values. If I use it is returning empty string.
Any ideas how to get timestamp of the first day of next month?

**SOLUTION**

```
$stat = Array('02.01.2012', '01.04.2012');
$start = new DateTime( $stat[0] );
$stop = new DateTime( $stat[1] );
while ( $start->format( 'U') <= $stop->format( 'U' ) ) {
    $counter ++;
    echo $start->format('d:m:Y') . '<br>';
    $start->modify( 'first day of next month' );
}
echo '::' . $counter . '..<br>';
```

Comment: I'm not sure is this would help you, but the issue can be in locality, for example `02.01.2012` can be 1st of February and 2nd of January.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$stat = Array('02.01.2012', '07.04.2012');
$stop = strtotime($stat[1]);
list($d, $m, $y) = explode('.', $stat[0]);
$count = 0;
while (true) {
    $m++;
    $cursor = mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y);
    if ($cursor < $stop) $count ++; else exit;
}
echo $count;
?>
```

the easy way :D

Comment: unfortunately your example doesnt work. I thought even it is a good base to invent something on my own, but i guess it is not. Now working with datetime object in php5.3 - hope to find solution

Comment: there is no error, script returns nothing. fortunatelly i found solution - it's in my post